# Javascript object - Delete repeating id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below sample javascript array object -

```
[ {id:"B1",name:"Belacost",group:"Quim"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Medtown",group:"Bik"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Regkim",group:"Dum"},
  {id:"C1",name:"CSet",group:"Core"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Merigo",group:"Dian"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Chilland",group:"Ground"},
  {id:"N1",name:"Fiwkow",group:"Vig"},
]
```

In this array I want to make id as empty if it repeats.

```
Eg. [ {id:"B1",name:"Belacost",group:"Quim"}, //id is here since this is first time
      {id:"",name:"Medtown",group:"Bik"}, //id is blank since we already have B1
      {id:"",name:"Regkim",group:"Dum"},
      {id:"C1",name:"CSet",group:"Core"},
      {id:"D1",name:"Merigo",group:"Dian"}, // id is here since D1 is first time
      {id:"",name:"Chilland",group:"Ground"}, //id is empty since we already have id D1
      {id:"N1",name:"Fiwkow",group:"Vig"},
    ]
```

I tried to achive it through map , but could not find repeat id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `reduce` method

```js
const list = [ {id:"B1",name:"Belacost",group:"Quim"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Medtown",group:"Bik"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Regkim",group:"Dum"},
  {id:"C1",name:"CSet",group:"Core"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Merigo",group:"Dian"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Chilland",group:"Ground"},
  {id:"N1",name:"Fiwkow",group:"Vig"},
]


const result = list.reduce((acc, item ) => { 
  
  const isExisting = acc.some(i => i.id === item.id)
  
  if(isExisting){
     return [...acc, {...item, id: ""}]
  }
  
  return [...acc, item]

}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Smal improvement: instead of storing existingItem you should only store the boolean with the usage of `some`. --> `const idExists = acc.some(i => i.id === item.id); if (idExists)...` Even better, reduce the rdundant field to store the boolean and move the some to the if expression directly.

Comment: Good suggestion @MoxxiManagarm. updated

Answer (score 4):

We can also do it with `Array.map` and `Array.some()`

```js
let data = [ {id:"B1",name:"Belacost",group:"Quim"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Medtown",group:"Bik"},
  {id:"B1",name:"Regkim",group:"Dum"},
  {id:"C1",name:"CSet",group:"Core"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Merigo",group:"Dian"},
  {id:"D1",name:"Chilland",group:"Ground"},
  {id:"N1",name:"Fiwkow",group:"Vig"},
]

let result = data.map((e,i,a) =>{
  let exists = a.slice(0,i).some(d => d.id === e.id)
  e.id = exists? "": e.id
  return e
})
console.log(result)
```